# Wordpress jCarousel jQuery Conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jcarousel

URL: http://oscarjacobs.rapdevs.co.uk/

When I include a link to jquery-1.9.1.min.js in my header, my jCarousel featured slider works, but my main slide show at the top stops working.

I found http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/ and added the following to my theme's functions.php file...

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

My jCarousel featured slider still doesn't work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you include jQuery maybe two times? in header and after/in slider?

Comment: @idonteven, that's what I suspected as well, but no he didn't.

Comment: was only my first thought. Thanks.

Comment: I saw that you used `jquery.noConflict()`. Try replacing all `$` with `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("ul.products").last().addClass("jcarousel-skin-tango");
    jQuery('ul.jcarousel-skin-tango').attr('id', 'mycarousel')
</script>
```

Here it is working - http://jsbin.com/eruweb/1

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I wasn't looking forward to replacing all $ with jquery.

Didn't have much faith in find and replace, even with including the open bracket in the search.

I've made the change you suggested, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

I checked my source code to make sure my changes had been uploaded successfully.

Any ideas why my copy still wouldn't be working, yet your link works a treat?

Comment: jquery should equal jQuery <- note the capital Q

Comment: Oh dear! Many apologies... Not a good start to the week!
Many thanks for your help and input from others.